# Is Channels is the best choice to send/handle one time events from view models to fragments/activities?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I'm trying to send events through using sealed class in view models to send events to fragments or activities like showing snack bar or toast and I was wondering, is channel the best choice over flows or shared flows?

Comment: I would say there is no best choice for that. Everyone chooses their own approach depending on the app architecture and style.

Comment: If you only want to use each message once ever, Channels seem to make more sense than Flows.

Comment: @Tenfour04 can u explain how channels use each message once ever?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you read this article: [ViewModel: One-off event antipatterns](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodel-one-off-event-antipatterns-16a1da869b95).

Basically, it argues why you should transform one-off events into state, and modify the state with functions from the ViewModel.

Example: State says that a snackbar is to be shown. The UI shows the snackbar and then tells the ViewModel that it was shown. The ViewModel updates the state accordingly, so the snackbar will not be shown again.